# Unable to get Theme id

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm unable to get the theme id (althought I have the theme)

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ListInterface;

/**
 * @var ListInterface
 */
private $themes;

public function __construct(ListInterface $themes){
    $this->themes = $themes;
}


private function getTheme($theme_needle){
    foreach ($this->themes as $theme){
        /** @var Theme $theme */
        $themeTitle = $theme->getThemeTitle(); //this return the good value
        if($themeTitle == $theme_needle){
            //var_dump($theme->getThemeId()); this return null
            //var_dump($theme->getCode()); this return the good value
            return $theme->getId(); // this return null
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

theme database content

[image: theme db content]

EDIT : This will do the trick but I can't figure out what is wrong with the other one method

```
            $select = $conn->select()
                ->from(
                  ['t' => 'theme'],
                  ['theme_id']
                )
                ->where(
                    't.theme_title=?',$theme_needle
                );
            $theme_id = $conn->fetchOne($select);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ThemeProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\DesignInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Theme\Model\ResourceModel\Theme\CollectionFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class CommandTest extends Command
{

    const NAME_ARGUMENT = "name";
    const NAME_OPTION = "option";

    /**
     * Core store config
     *
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @var ThemeProviderInterface
     */
    private $themeProvider;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ThemeProviderInterface $themeProvider
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     */

    public function __construct (
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ThemeProviderInterface $themeProvider,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->themeProvider = $themeProvider;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct();
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute (
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    )
    {
        $this->getTheme('Magento Luma');
        return 1;
    }

    private function getTheme(string $themeCode)
    {
        $themeList = $this->collectionFactory->create();

        foreach ($themeList as $theme) {
            /** @var  $theme */
            $themeTitle = $theme->getThemeTitle(); //this return the good value


            if ($themeTitle === $themeCode) {
                return $theme->getId();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure ()
    {
        $this->setName("test:test");
        parent::configure();
    }
```

This is a command class that i used for debug what are you looking for.
Cheers now!

Comment: Yes I already saw that but I don't want the current theme, I want to get a theme id using his title in order to add it to some specific stores during a module install.

Comment: updated the comment @Claims

Comment: Still getting `NULL` this way; I mean I still have the possibility to request directly the `theme` table but I was hoping this could have work without it.

Comment: post the result of this query please
select count(*)
from theme
where theme_id is null;

Comment: The count for null is 0, I will add to my first message the select, but there is 4 theme only and all of them have a theme_id.
I'm requesting the 4

Comment: i updated and posted a tested class, i want my points ahaha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111409/discussion-between-riccardo-ugolini-and-claims).

Comment: I think I will just drop it and go for an sql request. Trying to retrieve for Luma still returns null. We might have a missconfiguration somewhere. I think your solution should work even if it doesn't.

Comment: wait man, come on chat for discuss about it better